# Configuring JAAS on OC4J

Tags: java, jaas, oc4j

I'm trying to get JAAS working with OC4J.
I've gotten JAAS working before with JBoss. Using JAAS with JBoss is simple (to me).

In the app's jboss-web.xml, put this:

```
<security-domain>java:/jaas/myApp</security-domain>
```

And put the following in JBoss's login-config.xml:

```
<application-policy name = "myApp">
   <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag = "required">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName">java:/jdbc/myDS</module-option>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery">SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery">select name, 'Roles' from groups ...</module-option>
      </login-module>
   </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

So what's the equivalent in OC4J? Do I really need to deal with Realms, UserManagers, etc, or can I just add some XML in the system-jazn-data.xml file? What's the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did some more homework and found out that it's close. You need to add this to $OC4J_HOME/j2ee/yourinstance/config/system-jazn-data.xml

```
<application>
  <name>myApp</name>
  <login-modules>
    <login-module>
      <class>com.company.project.JDBCLoginModule</class>
      <control-flag>required</control-flag>
      <options>
        <option>
          <name>principalsQuery</name>
          <value>SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?</value>
        </option>
        <option>
          <name>dsJndiName</name>
          <value>jdbc/myDS</value>
        </option>
      </options>
    </login-module>
  </login-modules>
</application>
```

You then have to create the JDBCLoginModule class, which implements `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`. Maybe OC4J already has that class, but I couldn't find it. Include that class in your EAR/WAR/JAR that gets deployed to OC4J.

Still working on the groups/roles aspect of login.

UPDATE:
Even better, found the official web pages:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28957/jaas_intro.htm
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28957/loginmod.htm#BABCDDAI

Answer (score 1):

a) Actually, the best way is to put that on the orion-applcation and it will be installed automatically everytime the application is deployed: It will look something like

```
<jazn-loginconfig>
  <application>
    <name>ApplicationName</name>
    <login-modules>
      <login-module>
        <class>mycomapany.idm.loginmodules.BlahBlahLoginModule</class>
        <control-flag>required</control-flag>
        <options>
          <option>
          <name>debug</name>
          <value>true</value>
          </option>
        </options>
      </login-module>
    </login-modules>
  </application>
</jazn-loginconfig>
```

b) You should check JAZN which is the Oracle implementation/replacement for JAAS. It is more robust and flexible (although more complex). Now if you login logic is as simple as you posted above, I think that will be enough.